# Is there an easy way to hold a stabilizer?

Tags: stabilisation

I recently purchased this stabilizer in order to shoot some video footage:

https://www.walimex-webshop.com/en/walimex-pro-dslr-steadycam-stabypod-m-80cm.html

The stabilizer is easily balanced and I am not using all the counter weights since I shoot with a lightweight mirrorless camera. Yet after using it for a few minutes I feel a pain in my arm so I can not continue holding it steadily.

I have seen many videos in YouTube which demonstrate how to hold and move with it, yet none mentions the fatigue which shortly appears.

I wonder whether it is what it is or if I am doing something wrong. Maybe a gimbal would be more easy to use?

Any tip or personal experience sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: How far are you reaching your arm out? Remember the closer you keep it to your body, the less fatiguing it will be.

Comment: @Dr Mayhem Yes indeed, but holding it too close to the body will not absorb the vertical  vibrations as if extended, plus it will prevent the easy movement of the man who holds it, right?

Comment: When I'm using any sort of stabiliser I hold it no further than a foot away from my body - that gives ample room for movement, and means I can work half a day without fatigue